# fill a pandas column with a non-empty condition

Tags: python, pandas

I've got two panas dataframe, and I would like to generate one more with them:

```
import pandas as pd


df_name=pd.DataFrame({'CODE':['01','02','03','04'],
'NAME':['MICK','DAVID','JEAN','CHERRY']})

df_exp=pd.DataFrame({'TEST':['POST1','POST2','POST3','POST4','POST5','POST6','POST7', 'POST8'],
'PERS CODE':['02','','','04','','02','','03'],
'PERS2 CODE':['03','01','02','01','04','02','01','05']})

print(df_name)
print(df_exp)

df_output=pd.DataFrame()
df_output['POST']=df_exp['TEST']
df_output['AGENT'] = df_exp['PERS CODE'].map(df_name.set_index('CODE')['NAME'])

print(df_output)
```

but I would like a condition: if the value is empty in 'PERS CODE' it take the Value of 'PERS2 CODE'

I

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use [`mask`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.mask.html) to fill the empty `'PERS CODE'` entries with those of `'PERS2 CODE'`:

```
df_output['AGENT'] = df_exp['PERS CODE'].mask(df_exp['PERS CODE'].eq(''), df_exp['PERS2 CODE']).map(df_name.set_index('CODE')['NAME'])
```

Comment: excuse me but if the cell is no empty but 'NaN' does it change something, becaus when I use it in another script, it doen't make the job... I found it!!! pd.isna(df_exp['PERS CODE'])

Comment: yes, you need to adjust the condition (1st argument) in `mask`: `df_exp['PERS CODE'].isna()` if these values are `None` or `np.nan` (which will be displayed as `NaN)`. Only in the unlikely case that the missing values are coded by the **string** `"NaN"` you'd need `df_exp['PERS CODE'].eq('NaN')`